# What is the Tear of the Land?

Tags: legend-of-grimrock

I'm trying to solve the puzzle at level 9, where you need to place one item on each of the four slots. The Tear of the Land is the only one I can't figure out. What is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Tear of the Land is just a plain old rock. Any rock in your inventory will work... it's not a special one.

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now.